# javapackager: Cannot determine which JRE/JDK exists in the specified runtime directory. MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, javapackager

When I run

```
javapackager \
-deploy \
-Bruntime="/Users/david/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.2/Contents/Home" \
-native image \
-name "Sermon Viewer" \
-title "Sermon Viewer" \
-srcdir . \
-outdir . \
-srcfiles SermonViewer.jar \
-appclass Main \
-outfile SermonViewer \
-nosign \
-v
```

It returns

```
com.oracle.tools.packager.ConfigException:
 Cannot determine which JRE/JDK exists in the specified runtime directory.
```

I can compile just fine from with Intellij and the directory does exist.

I've also tried:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

and removed -Bruntime but same error.